# How Do I make the function "addlevels" work in my main code?

Tags: python, class, methods

I am currently taking an online python class and am having issues with classes and methods. My teacher wants me to use the method "addlevels" to print out the original strength points + points in "addlevels" method.

I've tried to put return down in the method, but that did not work. I've also tried using Hero.strengthsPtsAdded and print(str(Hero.strengthPtsAdded)) but that also hasn't worked. When using str(Hero.strengthPts) it would only print out 90 instead of adding the 10 points.

```
class Superhero:

    def __init__(self, name = "", strengthPts = 1):
        self.name = name 
        self.strengthPts = strengthPts
    def addlevels(self, points = 10):
        strengthPtsAdded = self.strengthPts + points
def main():
    Hero = Superhero("Falcon", 90,)
    print("Name: " + Hero.name)
    print("Level: " + str(Hero.strengthPts))
    Hero.addlevels()
    print("Heroes level after training " + str(Hero.strengthPts) + " .")
main()
```

I expected the code to output the name Falcon, the original strength points which would be 90, and then the strength points after adding which should be 100. The results though were that this code did print the name "Falcon" and the original strength points, but the last line printed "Heroes level after training: 90, instead of 100.

Comment: Update `self.strengthPts` instead of introducing an otherwise unused local variable `strengthPtsAdded`.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a new variable strengthPts_modified so to preserve the original strengthPts if yow want to use it later.

```
class Superhero:

    def __init__(self, name = "", strengthPts = 1):
        self.name = name 
        self.strengthPts = strengthPts
        self.strengthPts_modified=self.strengthPts
    def addlevels(self, points = 10):
        self.strengthPts_modified += points
def main():
    Hero = Superhero("Falcon", 90,)
    print("Name: " + Hero.name)
    print("Level: " + str(Hero.strengthPts))
    Hero.addlevels()
    Hero.addlevels()
    print("Heroes level after training " + str(Hero.strengthPts_modified) + " .")
main()
```